# Mouse events when over firebug console

Tags: javascript, firebug, panning

I'm trying to implement a panning (drag&drop) functionality on my site google maps. For that I use the standard mouse-events (mousedown, mousemove, mouseup).

It works while moving the mouse inside the browser, even with leaving the browser while still panning, as the browser recognizes the mouse-events even outside the browser. But it does not work when moving the mouse over the Firebug console.

Google maps also stops the panning when the mouse moves over the Firebug console, but how does it know when the mouse is there? It needs to know it, because event if I do not release the mouse button and move back to the map, the panning is not active anymore.
So how does the google-map know when the mouse went to the console?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Google Maps that knows about the mouse cursor being over the Firebug window.

Instead I suspect it's Firebug catching and cancelling the `mousemove` and `mouseover` event.